# How to change many row to column

Tags: linux, awk, text-processing

I have a file as follows and want to change to column when find a specise line (here is `del_size   fq`).

```
$ cat file.txt
del_size    fq
0   13452
-1  13034
del_size    fq
0   13
-1  0
-2  2155
del_size    fq
0   6600
-1  8
-2  0
```

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box to generate tab-separated output which you can then pipe to column or import into Excel or whatever you need to do afterwards:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
/^del_size/ { ++numCols; rowNr=0  }
{ $1 = $1 }
NR==1 {
    empty = $0
    gsub(/[^[:space:]]+/,"",empty)
}
{
    cell[++rowNr,numCols] = $0
    numRows = (rowNr > numRows ? rowNr : numRows)
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            val = ((rowNr,colNr) in cell ? cell[rowNr,colNr] : empty)
            printf "%s%s", val, (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
del_size  fq     del_size  fq    del_size  fq
0         13452  0         13    0         6600
-1        13034  -1        0     -1        8
                 -2        2155  -2        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Complex GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk '{
         if (/^del_size/) {
             h = (h? h OFS : "") $0; cnt++;
             if (r_cnt > max_rows) max_rows = r_cnt;
             i = j = r_cnt = 0
         }
         else { 
             arr[cnt][++i] = $0;
             r_cnt++ 
         }
         next
     }
     END{
         print h;
         for (i = 1; i <= max_rows; i++) {
             for (j = 1; j <= cnt; j++) {
                 items = arr[j][i];
                 if (items == "") items = "" OFS "";
                 printf "%s%s", (j == 1 ? "" : OFS), items
             }
             print ""
         } 
     }' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
del_size    fq  del_size    fq  del_size    fq
0   13452   0   13  0   6600
-1  13034   -1  0   -1  8
        -2  2155    -2  0
```

Comment: The only thing gawk-specific in there is the use of multi-dimensional array syntax but there's no benefit gained in the rest of the code from using that. Just use `arr[a,b]` instead of `arr[a][b]` and it'll work in any awk.